# Rebind window navigation keys in Tmux

Tags: tmux

I'd like to rebind `previous-window` and `next-window` Tmux commands to `C-,` and `C-.` respectively. By default they are bound to `$prefix p` and `$prefix n`.

How do i do that? I tried something like

```
bind -n C-, previous-window
bind -n C-. next-window
```

but it does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every key can be used with the ctrl modifier in the terminal. The only keys with ctrl-characters are letters and the set `@[\]^_?` - these same characters are also available on most keyboards with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>2345678</kbd> (for the same characters in the same order; this places `C-@` on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> and `C-^` on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> for `C-_`, and backspace for `C-?`.

You may be able to set up your terminal emulator to send unique codes for these keys.

Comment: Thank you - I see now why it stubbornly refused to recognise those combinations.